# Having issue with fadeToggle(). Making Loading dots plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fadeout, fadein

[Here is the link of what I did.](http://jsbin.com/efunam/edit#preview)

Why is there stupid looking animation going on? Help me pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.hide() will break the space between the dots (display:none)...so the animation looks weird. You can work with opacity or visibility instead. see my jsbin edit http://jsbin.com/efunam/3/edit#preview